Almost all icons replaced by prohibition icon
Almost all icons are replaced by Prohibition icon, though everything works fine. Icons like Sound, Settings, Lock, Power off are intact. Attaching image for reference. The icons while taking screenshot have all turned to prohibition icon too.

Currently using Ubuntu 24.04
I have already tried the things mentioned below:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager

sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension

sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng

Have also tried upgrading to latest update

Did you find a solution for this? Thank you.

For me, this got fixed after the recent update from 24.04 to 24.10.

This basically tells you it's not finding the icons.
Did you try changing the theme? Try the steps outline here: How do I change the icon theme in Ubuntu? and change the icon theme to something else (see second answer mid-way where he shows running gnome-tweaks)
It's also possible it's a broken update.
I would start by trying the following :
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt-get --fix-broken --fix-missing install


Thank you for the answer. But this doesn't work. Changing the theme replaces all those icons with blank. I can click on the icon, and circle is visible while hovering, but the icon is not visible. see top right in the image.

I'm getting access denied on the link you posted. Open a terminal go to /usr/share/themes . Check if the themes you are using are there and check the permisisons (ls -la). You want them to be 755 (drwxr-xr-x)
